# How to debug WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging

I am having a really hard time with my app.
It is a simple app, using the MVC pattern & ET and also has a WCF project.

When I run the "native" console application, it runs like a charm, however when I run it through WCF something goes wrong and I get `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException` so I want to see where is this coming from. `Console.WriteLine()` didn't work so I am looking for other ways how to print what is happening when the WCF is running.

The thing is the WCF works for sure, simple methods as `listCustomers()` are returned without problem, but the most complex one, `FindPathFromAtoB()` fails for some reason. However, without WCF it is working without a problem.

Comment: Any reason why you can't run it locally and follow it through the debugger?

Comment: If it is really a simple app, switch to ASP.NET Web API and you can easily debug it. Web API itself is open source, and debugging it is much easier than WCF.

Comment: @LexLi I cannot, it's for my university project. We have to use WCF.

Comment: Running it through the debugger isn't going to work in a lot of situations in particular anything to do with Serialization.  I'd create unit tests to make sure the data going in and out of the service can serialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn on WCF logging which will help you to get to the bottom of the problem.

In your service config file, add the following section. This will set up 2 listeners. They are currently set up to log only errors but you can change the value of `switchValue` to log more.

You need to also change the path where the logs will be created (`initializeData` attribute). The worker process of the service needs to have write access to that path.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <!--set autoflush to false to increase performance -->
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
    <sources>
        <!-- message logging -->
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" logKnownPii="false" switchValue="Error">
            <listeners>
                <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
                    <filter type=""/>
                </add>
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <!--service model tracing-->
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Error" propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <!-- worker process account needs write access to the configured tracing directories -->
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" initializeData="c:\temp\messages.svclog" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
            <filter type=""/>
        </add>
        <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" initializeData="c:\temp\trace.svclog" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
            <filter type=""/>
        </add>
    </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Check more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Szymon answer is incomplete.  WCF logs can be extremely verbose and are difficult to impossible for a novice WCF developer to digest.  There's a tool called the Service Trace Viewer that you'll need to use to interpret the logs from your service.

Here's a good link...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751795(v=vs.110).aspx

Also if your client is a WCF client, you'll probably want to setup logging on both the client and server, you can load the logs for both the client and the server into the Service Trace Viewer and see the entire conversation.